# PrimeFaces Error StateHelper

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

What can I do to solve this mistake? This mistake occurs when I run my web application with primefaces, the application recognizes the library and the tags but something happens. If you can solve, please help me.
This my error
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.component.spinner.Spinner.getStateHelper()Ljavax/faces/component/StateHelper;
 at org.primefaces.component.spinner.Spinner.getStepFactor(Spinner.java:68)
 at org.primefaces.component.spinner.SpinnerRenderer.calculateFractionDigits(SpinnerRenderer.java:72)
 at org.primefaces.component.spinner.SpinnerRenderer.encodeScript(SpinnerRenderer.java:52)
 at org.primefaces.component.spinner.SpinnerRenderer.encodeEnd(SpinnerRenderer.java:45)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:649)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:261)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:257)
 at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.actuallyRenderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:427)
 at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:383)
 at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
 at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:140)
 at org.apache.myfaces.custom.ppr.PPRLifecycleWrapper.render(PPRLifecycleWrapper.java:84)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:187)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

This my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <description>Comma separated list of URIs of (additional) faces config files.
            (e.g. /WEB-INF/my-config.xml)
            See JSF 1.0 PRD2, 10.3.2
            Attention: You do not need to put /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml in here.
    </description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: "client" or "server" (= default)
            See JSF Specification 2.5.3</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (= default).
            Defines the amount (default = 20) of the latest views are stored in session.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>20</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (= default).
            If true (default) the state will be serialized to a byte stream before it
            is written to the session.
            If false the state will not be serialized to a byte stream.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (= default) and if
            org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION is true (= default)
            If true (default) the serialized state will be compressed before it
            is written to the session. If false the state will not be compressed.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in the
            rendered HTML output.
            If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
            that submits the corresponding form.
            If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
            will be added as url parameters.
            Default: "true"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is "human readable".
            i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
            influence the HTML code.
            Default: "true"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
            former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
            with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
            if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
            Default: "false"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description> Used for encrypting view state.  Only relevant for client side
      state saving.  See MyFaces wiki/web site documentation for instructions
      on how to configure an application for diffenent encryption strengths.
     </description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SECRET</param-name>
        <param-value>NzY1NDMyMTA=</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>
     Validate managed beans, navigation rules and ensure that forms are not nested.
    </description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>A class implementing the
      org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.AddResource
      interface. It is responsible to
      place scripts and css on the right position in your HTML document.
            Default: "org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource"
            Follow the description on the MyFaces-Wiki-Performance page to enable
            StreamingAddResource instead of DefaultAddResource if you want to
            gain performance.
    </description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ADD_RESOURCE_CLASS</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource</param-value>
        <!--param-value>org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.StreamingAddResource</param-value-->
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>
        A very common problem in configuring MyFaces-web-applications
        is that the Extensions-Filter is not configured at all
        or improperly configured. This parameter will check for a properly
        configured Extensions-Filter if it is needed by the web-app.
        In most cases this check will work just fine, there might be cases
        where an internal forward will bypass the Extensions-Filter and the check
        will not work. If this is the case, you can disable the check by setting
        this parameter to false.
    </description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Set the size limit for uploaded files.
                Format: 10 - 10 bytes
                        10k - 10 KB
                        10m - 10 MB
                        1g - 1 GB</description>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100m</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Set the threshold size - files
                    below this limit are stored in memory, files above
                    this limit are stored on disk.

                Format: 10 - 10 bytes
                        10k - 10 KB
                        10m - 10 MB
                        1g - 1 GB</description>
            <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100k</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SourceCodeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.util.servlet.SourceCodeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SourceCodeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.source</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I am using primefaces 2.0.0 Rc

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume version mismatch between primefaces and JSF. For Primefaces 2.0 I think you need JSF 2.0

Comment: Yes, PrimeFaces forum confirms that PrimeFaces 2.0 requires JSF 2.0.  Also, PrimeFaces 1.x is no longer supported, so if you cannot upgrade to JSF 2.0, you won't be able to use PrimeFaces.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I was using JSF 1.2 and I changed it to JSF 2.0 how you said and my application ran perfectly